# PowerShell + GitLab: How to parse gitlab variable to powershell array

Tags: arrays, powershell, gitlab

I'm trying to define an array in Powershell with the `@{}` notation, but since this is being done within a GitLab CI pipeline, I need to define the variable as a string.

So let's say I have something like this in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  array: '@{"key1" = @("valueA","valueB"); "key2" = @("valueC","valueD")}'

stages:
  - test_stage

test_job:
  stage: test_stage
  script:
    - >
      foreach ($key in $array.Keys){
        foreach ($value in $array[$key]){
          Write-Host "Key: $key , Value: $value"
        }
      }
```

I'd expect to get this output:

```
Key: key1 , Value: valueA
Key: key1 , Value: valueB
Key: key2 , Value: valueC
Key: key2 , Value: valueD
```

But I'm not getting anything, since GitLab CI is passing the variable to PowerShell as a string.

The question is, how can I parse this string in PowerShell so that it evaluates it as an array? I'd expect PowerShell to treat that variable like if I'd written it on the console like so:

```
$array = @{"key1" = @("valueA","valueB"); "key2" = @("valueC","valueD")}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Store JSON in the string variable:

```
variables:
  arrayTableJSON: '{"key2":["valueC","valueD"],"key1":["valueA","valueB"]}'
```

And then use `ConvertFrom-Json` in your script:

```
$arrayTable = $arrayTableJSON |ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
foreach ($key in $arrayTable.psbase.Keys){
    foreach ($value in $arrayTable[$key]){
        Write-Host "Key: $key , Value: $value"
    }
}
```